# Libreoffice 5 in ubuntu 15.10 raising system temperature

Tags: libreoffice, cpu, overheating, 15.10, temperature

I'm using 15.10 upgraded from 15.04 and when I open some documents with new Libreoffice5, the system temperature goes to 60-65ºC (or more!), when normally stands between 45º and 50º. Also, system-manager shows a high CPU usage and soffice.bin process never goes to a sleep state.

This only happens with new docs, if I open an old one (created before de system upgrade) temperature and CPU usage are both normal. Doesn't matter document size.

Surely it isn't related with hardware: Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8 and 15,6 GiB.

I could find nothing related googling. Some hint about where to look for what is happening?